# Which characters have been recast in the Harry Potter films?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, actors

Which characters in the Harry Potter films have been recast? As the same character being played by two different actors in different films.

### Which characters from the Harry Potter films have been recast?

Comment: Does that include using a different actor to play a character at a different age in flashbacks?

Comment: Cause, Snape, HP, Hagrid, etc have childhood version actors for playing their flashbacks.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are 17 :

1. **Griphook** : [Verne Troyer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verne_Troyer#Film) -> [Wawrick Davis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warwick_Davis)
   [image]
2. **Lavender Brown** : Jennifer Smith -> [Jessie Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessie_Cave)
   [image]
3. **Elphias Doge** : [Peter Cartwright](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Cartwright_(actor)) -> [David Ryall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Ryall)
   [image]
4. **Katie Bell** : Emily Dale -> [Georgina Leonidas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgina_Leonidas)
   [image]
5. **Tom The Innkeeper** : [Derek Deadman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derek_Deadman) -> [Jim Tavare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Tavar%C3%A9)
   [image]
6. **The Fat Lady** : [Elizabeth Spriggs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Spriggs) -> [Dawn French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_French)
   [image]
7. **Helena Ravenclaw** : [Nina Young](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nina_Young) -> [Kelly Macdonald](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelly_Macdonald)
   [image]
8. **Pansy Parkinson** : [Genevieve Gaunt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genevieve_Gaunt) -> [Scarlett Byrne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlett_Byrne)
   [image]
9. **Mafalda Hopkirk** : [Jessica Hynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jessica_Hynes) -> [Sophie Thompson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Thompson)
   [image]
10. **Professor Dumbledore** : [Richard Harris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Harris) -> [Michael Gambon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Gambon)
    [image]
11. **Voldemort** : [Richard Bremmer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Bremmer) -> [Ralph Fiennes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Fiennes) (this cost Voldemort his nose). (Edit: it was a joke I heard, but after reading again the books, it appears that he was described as looking like a snake since GoF)
    [image]
12. **Angelina Johnson** : [Danielle Tabor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danielle_Tabor) -> [Tiana Benjamin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiana_Benjamin)
    [image]
13. **Padma Patil** : Sharon Sandhu -> [Afshan Azad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afshan_Azad)
    [image]
14. **Parvati Patil** : Sitara Shah -> [Shefali Chowdhury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shefali_Chowdhury)
    [image]
15. **Alicia Spinnet** : [Leilah Sutherland](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leilah_Sutherland) -> Rochelle Douglas
    [image]
16. **Mr Granger** : Tom Knight -> Ian Kelly
17. **Mrs Granger** : Heather Bleasdale -> Michelle Fairley

---

Special section for young Tom Riddle actors :

- 11-year old : [Hero Fiennes-Tiffin](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hero_Fiennes-Tiffin)
- 16-year old : [Frank Dillane](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Frank_Dillane)
- 18-year old : [Michael Berendt](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Michael_Berendt)
- Young in CoS : [Christian Coulson](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Christian_Coulson)

Comment: Err... I am sure I am outing myself as a noob here, but why was it the re-cast that "cost Voldemort his nose"?

Comment: @DevSolar I wrote it as a joke 'cause I'm not really sure about my source. But I remember something about too many differences between Bremmer and Fiennes, so they had to cut his nose.

Comment: @Saphirel: Ah, ok... on research, turns out the book (GoF) indeed describes his nose as "flat as a snake’s with slits for nostrils". I just wondered if I had missed something. ;-)

Comment: Filipe De Sousa and Pete Hooper have pointed out some more recastings.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35516/discussion-on-answer-by-saphirel-which-characters-have-been-recast-in-the-harry).

Comment: I think some of these are assumptions. We don't know that that goblin was Griphook for example, or the ghost is the Grey Lady.

Comment: Was Richard Harris the only one of this bunch that was recast on account of him dying?

Comment: Bill Weasley, Charlie Weasley, and Cedric Diggory.

Comment: @Saphirel Honestly, the comparison between a Howler and the photo of the actress playing Mafalda Hopkirk doesn't make much sense. As far as I know, the Howler doesn't necessarily resemble its sender.

Comment: @A.Darwin The actress changed. Acting doesn't necessary mean showing your face in front of a camera. Sometimes, you juste have to speak :)

Comment: @Saphirel Got it. I didn't remember the difference between the two voices:)

Comment: so I wouldn't exactly call late Richard Harris dying of old age as "recasting". Probably worth noting in the post...

Comment: can't shake the feeling they considered a Brown to be played by a black person too prone to be perceived as a bad joke and reinstalled the black person as Johnson instead. Well if they picked me for being tall playing Mr. Tall or being short and playing Mr. Short I'd say good lough for them but anyway... Were this story true I would just feel sorry for J. Smith and Tabor.

Comment: Dumbledore and Grindelwald have been recast for *Fantastic Beasts*.

Comment: I think number 7 is incorrect. The shot of Marcus seems to be from Chamber of Secrets, and yet the actor that supppsedly replaces him definitely played Marcus in Philosopher's stone, and reprises his role in the shot in which this screenshot was taken.

Comment: There’s one you’ve left out, who the Wiki says was played by _at least_ seven different, erm, actors: **Fang**, apparently played by Hugo, Bully, Bella, Vito, Luigi, Monkey, and Uno. Also, I believe, the only named character to be played by actors of different genders.

Comment: Wow, the actress that played young Pancy Parkinson is actually Gaunt! Pancy would be thrilled she is related to Gaunts :)

Answer (score 9):

Some recast roles and the actors are:

1. **Infant Harry Potter**: [Saunders Triplets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Harry_Potter_cast_members#endnote_TripletsA)
2. **Dumbledore**: Michael Gambon, Richard Harris
3. **Rubeus Hagrid**: Robbie Coltrane, Martin Bayfield (young version, CoS)
4. **Snape**: Alan Rickman, Alec Hopkins(OotP), Benedict Clarke(DH)
5. **Lavender Brown**: Jennifer Smith(PoA), Jessie Cave
6. **Angelina Johnson**: Danielle Tabor, Tiana Benjamin(GoF)
7. **Ernie Macmillan**: Louis Doyle, Jamie Marks (DH)
8. **Padma Patil**: Sharon Sandhu(PoA), Afshan Azad
9. **Parvati Patil**: Sitara Shah(PoA),    Shefali Chowdhury
10. **Alicia Spinnet**: Leilah Sutherland(PS), Rochelle Douglas(CoS)

Answer (score 8):

Robert Pattinson appeared as Cedric Diggory, who was recast for GoF. It doesn't look like the original actor for Cedric in PoA was identified.
I've not been able to find a credit for Cedric in PoA, in the film credits or on IMDb.
See [his wiki page](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cedric_Diggory#Behind_the_scenes).

Comment: Nice find, and a good first post.  Welcome to scifi SE!  Induction ceremony at midnight tonight.  Bring a knife and a vial of blood!  ;)

Answer (score 5):

### Bill Weasley.

From http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/William_Weasley#Behind_the_scenes :

> Bill is portrayed by English actor Richard Fish in the film adaptation of Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban and Irish actor Domhnall Gleeson, son of Brendan Gleeson, in Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 1 and Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows: Part 2.

Answer (score 2):

The only one I know is **Albus Dumbledore**, played by:

- Richard Harris (films 1–2)
- Michael Gambon (films 3-8)
- Toby Regbo (playing the young Albus Dumbledore)

source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albus_Dumbledore)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, Grindelwald was played by Jamie Campbell Bower (young) and Michael Byrne (old). If we're allowing crossing wizarding world franchises, you can also include Johnny Depp and Mads Mikkelson (not Colin Farrell, because he was an in-universe disguise, rather than a switch we shouldn't have noticed).

[image][image][image]

Flitwick certainly *looks* like he has been, but it's actually the same actor in both cases.

[image]
[image]